# Cannot set property 'router' of undefined

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I keep getting the following error when trying to navigate to "upload" page in Angular 2.

> Cannot set property 'router' of undefined.

My Code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router} from '@angular/router';
export class GameLandingComponent implements OnInit{
    ngOnInit(){
        //some codes and logics...
        this.router= Router;
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/upload');
    }
}
```

Appreciate if someone could give me some help.TIA.

Answer (score 1):

You need to inject router inside the constructor and you are missing constructor
Try this -

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router} from '@angular/router';
export class GameLandingComponent implements OnInit{

    constructor(private router: Router){

    }

    ngOnInit(){

        this.router.navigateByUrl('/upload');
    }
}
```

Comment: i think there is no need to make this.router = Router

Comment: Apologies! Was trying to post the entire code to make it easy to understand.

Comment: thanks for the quick response. Unfortunately, I still getting the same error after adding the constructor. :(

Comment: did you remove the part where you assign this.router

Comment: did you add routerModule in providers in app.module ?

Comment: @KhaledAhmed yea i had this "import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';" in my app.module.ts.

Answer (score 0):

it is not the way that you inject a class with
inject it in the constructor

```
constructor(private router: Router){}
/// router now a private member of your class
```